# Hadoop namenode ui:HTTP ERROR 404

Tags: hive, hbase, hiveql, hadoop2

Facing problem while accessing hadoop namenode ui: http://172.18.130.130:50070/dfshealth.html#tab-overview

It was working fine before but after multiple hadoop restart now it is not showing and giving below error message though hadoop is working fine so does all the operations.

```
HTTP ERROR 404

Problem accessing /dfshealth.html. Reason:

NOT_FOUND
Powered by Jetty://
```

Please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: Have you looked for errors in namenode logs?

Comment: yes,,i cant see any messages for this error message in name node log file..

Comment: Do you see any error in namenode logs?

Comment: No .It is just normal log entries for edit logs:
 Below are last few lines of namenode.


2016-10-19 14:29:32,756 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FileJournalManager: Finalizing edits file /u01/DSSBP/DSS_PLATFORM/had
oop-2.7.2/full/dfs/name/current/edits_inprogress_0000000000000289531 -> /u01/DSSBP/DSS_PLATFORM/hadoop-2.7.2/full/dfs/name/current/edits_
0000000000000289531-0000000000000289561
2016-10-19 14:29:32,757 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLog: Starting log segment at 289562

Comment: Have you try by restarting the services

Comment: Yes ,i have tried that too,,but did not format the cluster as it will delete all the datas.

Comment: @RanjanSwain if you get an answer pls share it